# Can I write custom rule in a simple java project for sonar Qube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Can I write custom rule in a simple java project for sonar Qube and add it to sonarqube instance or do I have to write my custom rule in a maven project only.

Answer (score 2):

Only Maven is supported for plugins.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I found this https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode Does this mean I cannot use maven and still do it.

Comment: @TejeshviRane the document you linked explains how to provide required parameters to the Java analyzer when using a non-Maven **scanner**. It has absolutely nothing to do with custom plugin development.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) explains how to write custom Java rules using Maven.
You *could* follow the steps and instead of using Maven,
perform manually what the Maven steps would do.
Among other things: download the dependencies,
with correct versions,
and create a plugin package correctly.
All the source code is available,
so doing this is entirely possible.
It's likely to be a tedious, boring procedure,
that's why we provide Maven tools to make this easier and painless.
As @Ann said, we don't provide support if you go without Maven,
and we don't recommend it.